# LDAP : exclude a domain from search query

Tags: search, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query, dn

I an trying to exclude a domain controller from my LDAP search.

I have 3 DC : `staff`, `student` and `exams`.

So I can use on of the following search DN :

- `DC=staff,DC=root,DC=mycompany,DC=fr`
- `DC=student,DC=root,DC=mycompany,DC=fr`
- `DC=exams,DC=root,DC=mycompany,DC=fr`

Then the search is simple : `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=johndoe))`

It works, but a person (`sAMAccountName`) can be under several domains (ie. student and exam), so it is found twice. I need to restrict the search to **only `staff` and `student`**.

I tried the following query but in does not work :

`(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=johndoe)(!(memberOf=DC=exams,DC=root,DC=mycompany,DC=fr)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up your DC's and groups.  `memberOf` is a reverse pointer attribute in Active Directory; it is maintained on the user object but corresponds directly to the groups to which the user is a member.  If you actually had your different members in groups that corresponded to your domain you could do something like that.  It would look more like this though...

```
(&
  (objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=johndoe)
  (!(memberOf=cn=exams_group,ou=groups,DC=exams,DC=root,DC=mycompany,DC=fr))
)
```

If that does not look like it will work for you, take a look at your `userPrincipalName` attribute values for each entry.  It is possible that they all have different extensions.  The `userPrincipalName` is guaranteed unique across the forest and is generally in the format of an email address `samaccountname@domainname`.  If you have duplicate samaccountnames across domains there is a good chance the domain component of the userprincipalname will be different.

You could do something like this... a bit crude but maybe effective

```
(&
  (objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=johndoe)
  (!(userprincipalname=*@exams.root.mycompany.fr))
)
```

Or you could just submit multiple positive search requests.

Comment: We don't have a specific group for exams. But you're right about the `userPrincipalName` ! The domain component is different (_exams.root.mycompany.fr_ vs _mycompany.ch_) so I can just do the restriction on that attribute. The query : `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=johndoe)(!(userprincipalname=*@exam.root.mycompany.fr)))`. Thank you!